# This equation keep giving me error messages

Tags: equations, compilation-error

I am trying to post a  explanation on aops and it keeps saying

> Error compiling LaTeX. ! File ended while scanning use of \align*.

Please get back ASAP, it's homework thanks in advance.

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{6\sqrt{{(x+1)(x+3)+1}-12}{2x}\\
&=\frac{6\sqrt{x^2+4x+3+1}-12}{2x}\\
&=\frac{6\sqrt{x^2+4x+4}-12}{2x}\\
&=\frac{6(x+2)-12}{2x}\\
&=\frac{6x+12-12}{2x}\\
&=\frac{6x}{2x}=3
\end{align*}
```

Comment: On the first line, you have two openig braces in `\sqrt{{...` where only one should be.  I didn't check further.  Hint: count braces as "open, +1; close: -1".  You should end up at zero at the end of each line or logical group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

- `align*` environment enters math mode for you, so there is node need to wrap it in between `$$ ... $$`.
- The left brace of numerator of first `\frac` is never closed by a pairing right brace.
- You might need `& \mathrel{\phantom{=}}` prepended to first line of `align*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
     & \mathrel{\phantom{=}}\frac{6\sqrt{{(x+1)(x+3)+1}-12}}{2x} \\
     & =\frac{6\sqrt{x^2+4x+3+1}-12}{2x}                         \\
     & =\frac{6\sqrt{x^2+4x+4}-12}{2x}                           \\
     & =\frac{6(x+2)-12}{2x}                                     \\
     & =\frac{6x+12-12}{2x}                                      \\
     & =\frac{6x}{2x}=3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your problems is already solved in other answers, but you may liked the following solution which employ the instruction `\MoveEqLeft` defined in the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft[3]
\frac{6\sqrt{{(x+1)(x+3)+1}-12}}{2x}        \\
     & =\frac{6\sqrt{x^2+4x+3+1}-12}{2x}     
       =\frac{6\sqrt{x^2+4x+4}-12}{2x}      \\ & =\frac{6(x+2)-12}{2x}                 
       =\frac{6x+12-12}{2x}                 \\
     & =\frac{6x}{2x}=3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

Comment: Very nice...but I have finished my votes. Sorry.

Comment: @Sebastiano, me too. Today I cannot receive any vote anymore :-)

Answer (score 1):

Errors in the first line are the cause, ie mismatched `{ }`. A fix is:

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{6\sqrt{(x+1)(x+3)+1}-12}{2x}
&=\frac{6\sqrt{x^2+4x+3+1}-12}{2x} \\
&=\frac{6\sqrt{x^2+4x+4}-12}{2x} \\
&=\frac{6(x+2)-12}{2x} \\
&=\frac{6x+12-12}{2x} \\
&=\frac{6x}{2x} = 3
\end{align*}
```

which produces:

[image]